# How to train string feature as word embedding vectors as part of a Linear Regression Tensorflow model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, vector, word-embedding

How do I train string feature as word embedding vectors as part of a linear regression Tensorflow model? I found example online about how to uses Tensorflow to vectorize strings and use these vectors as the x-inputs to train the model like below:

```
tokenizer = Tokenizer(oov_token=oov_token,num_words=num_words)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(sentences)
word_index = tokenizer.word_index
sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(sentences)
padded_sequences = pad_sequences(sequences, padding='post', maxlen=maxlen)

model = tf.keras.Sequential([ 
        tf.keras.layers.Embedding(num_words, embedding_dim, input_length=maxlen),
        tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D(),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation='relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.3),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(5, activation="softmax")
    ])
```

But I want to train the word embedding vector along with other features/x-inputs (integers, floats) and not only with word embedding vector like the example above... How should I do this? Is there a way to vectorize individual string so I can replace the columns (in my datset) that have string values with new columns that have vector values?

I want to train 17 features/x-inputs (including the word embedding feature) to produce 2 output features. I had prepared my train_data_set as below so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dataset = pd.read_sql_query(all_data.statement, engine)
train_dataset = dataset.sample(frac=0.8, random_state=0)
train_x_inputs = np.copy(train_dataset)
train_x_inputs = np.delete(train_x_inputs,[0,1,3,4,5,6],axis=1).astype(np.float32)
normalizer = tf.keras.layers.Normalization(axis=-1)
normalizer.adapt(train_x_inputs)
```

I'm following this basic linear regression example from Tensorflow, so I'm thinking of building an ML model as below:

```
def build_and_compile_model(norm):
  model = keras.Sequential([
      norm,
      layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
      layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
      layers.Dense(2)
  ])

  model.compile(loss='mean_absolute_error',
                optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.001))
  return model
```

But I really don't know how to fit the Embedding vectors into the model above...Or maybe Word Embedding is no need for my case, if so, could you recommend me the best method to convert string features into numerical values that I can use to train with Tensorflow Model? (Should I uses Label Encoder instead of Word Embedding?)

Thank you!

Comment: In Keras you can create one input for the embedding output and concat with other input that contains the 17 features. Take a llok to the doc https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/functional

Comment: Thank you! I'm reading the tutorial.